# Op amp output load

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio

I'm using an audio op amp (LME49726) to combine two audio sources together, to be listened to with headphones at its output. Whenever I plug in the headphones, there is a large voltage drop in the supply voltage and it doesn't work. What could be the problem with having a headphone load at the output? What op amp parameters would this involve? I have also tried a general purpose op amp with the same result. This is datasheet of the audio op amp: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lme49726.pdf
Here's the simple circuit:
[image]

Comment: Second line of the datasheet : "Easily drives 2 kilohm loads". What impedance are your headphones? If they are less than 2 kilohms ... no go.

Comment: I didn't realize that meant you cannot drive a load below 2k...is there an actual parameter in the characteristics that indicates this?

Comment: What are you using for a power supply? And a schematic of your circuit would be helpful too.

Comment: *is there an actual parameter * Forget the parameters, just read what this opamp is designed for. Does it say "headphone amplifier" anywhere ? I could not find it. Obviously this amplifier is not meant for driving headphones.

Comment: The power supply is a AAA battery with a 5V step up voltage regulator (https://www.pololu.com/product/2562).

Comment: Actually it does describe behaviour into Rl=16 ohms. So if that meets your needs, you have to look into beefing up the power supply as the answer suggests.

Comment: @FakeMoustache: Are you suggesting that every opamp datasheet lists every application the opamp can be used for?!

Comment: @psmears no of course not because an opamp is a very generic component. And although this LME49726 is technically an opamp, it is designed for audio line driving. So that's why it says so on the datasheet. If you're looking for a headphone amplifier then look for a chip which is designed for that and that will be listed in the datasheet.

Comment: And next time, include the schematic from the start as then we could have immediately pointed out that you need a DC blocking capacitor at the output !

Answer (score 8):

That particular op-amp is capable of hundreds of mA output current. I think you should be able to deafen yourself if the headphones are the normal rare-earth ~30\$\Omega\$ variety.

You seem to have identified part of the problem- the supply voltage drops. You need to capacitively couple the headphones. What you have now attempts to put 2.5VDC across the headphones, which is at least 83mA, thereby dragging down your supply.

Try a 100uF electrolytic in series with the output (+ side to the op-amp, - to the headphones).

Comment: Ah that's the problem, I forgot to do that, thanks!!

Comment: @cheeto if that kind of cap is too bulky or you don't have one at hand, you can also stabilise the 2.5 V level with another OP and use it as the headphone's ground. Or implement a proper push-pull by inverting the signal once more. But that's arguably overkill for headphones.

Comment: Why does the output coupling capacitor need to be as high as 100 uF and be electrolytic? What about a 10 uF ceramic cap?

Comment: It does not need to be electrolytic, but 100uF is pretty small and maintains bass response. You can work out the -3dB frequency. 10uF ceramic would limit the low end response and probably add a lot of audible distortion, but if you can't hear any difference why not.

Comment: Would you calculate the output coupling capacitor you need for your desired frequency response through the 1/(2*pi*RC) formula, with R being the headphone impedance?

Comment: Yes, that will give you the low frequency cutoff.

Answer (score 1):

If your power supply voltage is dropping then it indicates that the power supply is not capable of supplying the current to the load.

Many headphones are only 8 ohms.  Suppose you had an output signal level into the headphones of 1V you would need to supply up to 1V/8 ohms = 125mA.  If your signal level is higher you will need correspondingly more current.  For example at 4V you would need 0.5A. 

The LME49726 is capable of driving an 8 ohm load at signal levels up to 2.8V with a 5V supply and is easily capable of driving typical headphones.

The parameters that would typically be considered when driving headphones from an op-amp would be...

1)  Voltage headroom from each supply vs load current (also referred to output swing).

2)  Maximum load current.

3)  Maximum allowed wattage based on ambient temperature, junction temperature, and thermal resistance (theta-JA).  The power dissipation is approximately...
W =  Is * VCC + |Iout| * (VCC-Vout)  when sourcing current out of the output pin.
W =  Is * VCC + |Iout| * Vout  when sinking current into the output pin.

4)  Also with respect to audio outptut quality you would consider CMRR, input offset voltage, gain bandwidth product, and linearity.

Comment: Most headphones are 30 ohms, speakers mostly 8 ohms.

Comment: If this op amp should be cable of driving headphones, I wonder why I'm having this problem. I attached a drawing of the op amp configuration...

Comment: I am **very** curious where you found that the LME49726 can drive 8 ohms because I don't see that anywhere in the datasheet. The lowest impedance they mention is 600 ohms. Perhaps I am overlooking some information ?

Comment: @FakeMoustache It says on page 4 of the datasheet that the output swing is VDD-0.33V with a 16 ohm load.  It also says that it can typically drive 350mA.  So as long as you keep the output swing far enough from the rails it can drive the load.

Comment: OK I see that, but since the distortion specs. are only for a 600 ohm load I have my doubts if this opamp has proper performance (low enough distortion) to actually drive 16 ohms. I'd still choose a headphone amp to drive a headphone. This opamp is still a line driver.

Comment: Both the comment in the OP and this answer seem to ignore the restriction on 16 ohm outputs - the load is expected to be connected to Vdd /2. Using a grounded load more than doubles the current required for positive excursions.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast If the datasheet is assuming the load is connected to Vdd/2 they are probably assuming the use of a rail splitter.  8 ohms, 30 ohms, or 1 ohm load doesn't matter as long as the voltage across the load is low enough to stay within the output current limitation of 350mA.  It appears that the voltage drop mentioned in the original post was momentary rather than continuous (he didn't say one way or another and I thought it was continuous), so a decoupling capacitor should fix it as was already recommended.

Comment: At first the schematic was not there so we had no idea OP was trying to apply **2.5 V DC** to his headphones.